# Binding .click to toggleClass("hidden") on newly inserted PHP content. Event Bubbling?

Tags: jquery, ajax, binding, event-bubbling

**Edit:** Thanks to K.K, I was able to solve this problem! The correctly working code is at the bottom of the post.

I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery, and I have been struggling with this problem for a couple days, but I wont give up!

All of my functions are under $(function () {, so they all load on the DOM being ready. I have a working button which load's content from a .php page, then the newly load'd content has ANOTHER button, which when clicked should do something basic, like remove the "hidden" class from an iFrame.

Below is the first button (I stripped the e.preventDefault from it just incase)

```
$(function() {
  $('.top5').click( function(e) {
    $("#currentactivity").html('<img src="./images/loading.gif" alt="loading" />').show();
    var url= "index.php";
    $.post(url, {q:$(this).attr('value')}, function(data){
      $("#currentactivity").html(data).show();
    });
  });
});
```

Below are two attempts at the 2nd button, neither work.

```
// using .live()
  $('body').live("click", function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("missionopen") {
      var $target = $('#missioniframe');
      if $target.hasClass("hidden") {
        $target.toggleClass("hidden");
      }
    });
  });

// Just plain event bubbling (Since body is already loaded?)
  $('body').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('missionopen')) {
      $('#missioniframe').toggleClass('hidden');
    }
  });
```

And here is button1, button2(Loaded from php), and the iframe HTML snippits.

```
<a href="#" class="top5" value="1"><img src="./images/qstata.png" /></a> 

<a href='#' class='missionopen' value='1'><img class='missionhero' src='./images/bluebutton1.png' /></a>

<iframe src='missioniframe.html' class='hidden' id='missioniframe' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' ></iframe>
```

**Working Code: Courtesy of K.K**

```
  $('body').on("click", ".missionopen", function(e) {
    $('#missioniframe').toggleClass("hidden");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: use .live() function directly on class.

Comment: That tiny sentence fixed my problem. Thank you so much =] <3